# How do you make the list of Organic Group (OG) members of a group visible only to group members?

Tags: organic-groups

In Drupal 7 I have public and private groups.  I would like the list of members that show up in the View: OG members block to only show members of the group if the the current user is a member of that group as well.

This seems like a fundamental capability of OG yet I can't seem to find how to set it.

A version of this question is at http://drupal.org/node/707738 - posted on February 8, 2010

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go in Views under `Block Settings > Access` and try OG Permissions

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up your og page as a node template, you will find the OG Members block in the content section of your page setup. If you click the gear icon on the block, you will see "Visibility Rules". Click "add new rule" and select "OG: user membership in group".

That's how I did it, and it worked for me.